# Do we want more migration paths?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

When you're voting to close a question as *off-topic* for tex.sx, the question might still be on-topic for one of the other [84 Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) (as of April '12). If [four out of five](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89242/162565) [3k users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) voting to close (or a diamond mod) vote to migrate a question to another site, it is migrated there. Currently, you can only migrate questions to meta.tex.sx because there aren't any other *migration paths*. We could, however, have up to [four more migration paths](https://meta.superuser.com/a/1704/90749), which would look somewhat like this:

[image]

While we don't migrate off-topic questions very often, I think we could do so much more often, whilst bearing in mind the first rule of migration: "Don't migrate crap." (Which gets an amusing [1,700 hits on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22don%27t%20migrate%20crap%22).)

I'll put some options in the comments for you to vote upon, and we'll see where this takes us. **Feel free to add more options.**

---

I think (diamond?) moderators can access migration statistics (I saw some on MSO) -- could one of them perhaps edit in our migration stats here?

Migration statistics for the [main site](http://tex.stackexchange.com) for the last 90 days (as of Friday, April 27, 2012):

[image]

Migration statistics for the [meta site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) for the last 90 days (as of Friday, April 27, 2012):

[image]

Comment: "I don't think we need any more migration paths."

Comment: "I'd like to have a migration path to [so]."

Comment: "I'd like to have a migration path to [su]."

Comment: "I'd like to have a migration path to [english.se]."

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have the suggestions as answers rather than comments, so that down votes can be cast?

Comment: @AlanMunn: Hmm, I didn't have down-votes in mind, or just didn't think they would be necessary. Well, I guess we can have a bunch of CW answers as well, it doesn't really matter to me.

Comment: "I'd like to have a migration path to [graphicdesign.se]"

Comment: "I'd like to have a migration path to [unix.se]"

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I was thinking about Graphic Design, but migration paths are usually not installed to beta sites (I read that somewhere on MSO, I think by Jeff.) We might still want to keep GD in mind and keep a slot open until it's established.

Comment: Do we really get questions that should be migrated to English Language and Usage?

Comment: @AlanMunn There have been a few questions that were kind of borderline – questions like "where do I put the index" and "what do I put in the index", which are not really TeX related. But there aren't many of them, and I don't know what is the stand of English Language and Usage on those questions (as it may be sort of off topic there too).

Comment: @ienissei: That kind of questions will be downvoted and closed as off-topic at ELU in under a second. With any luck some comment might refer to [writers.stackexchange.com](http://writers.stackexchange.com/). Therefore I would recommend not to migrate to ELU, but maybe to writers (when it is out of beta).

Comment: @Stephen Yes, those typography questions (I think all of them were about typography) don't really fit anywhere, and are not always language-specific either… but TeX being a typesetting system, I feel like we should welcome them here, for lack of a better place. They have been neither closed nor down-voted here, even though they weren't strictly-speaking "on topic" – and I think it is great that they were thus welcomed. A typography.SX probably wouldn't attract enough people anyway.

Comment: @ienussei: Yes, I'm supporting to keep typography questions here at TeX.SE. We have a [typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/typography/info) tag her, after all.

Comment: It will be better if the migration path is implemented dynamically by a drop down or list box control with a list of all possible options rather than statically implemented by a list of radio buttons with certain options. The feature should be propagated to all sites. :)

Comment: @Mod: That Feature request has been discussed and declined on [metase], iirc. Moderators, however, get such a list by default, i.e. they can migrate questions anywhere they like.

Comment: Looking at adjusting migration paths when only 3 questions have been migrated in the last 90 days...interesting. (;

Comment: @Rebecca: Wow, I wasn't aware that we migrate _this_ few questions (couldn't see the stats, as I don't have 10k rep); I think I was involved in at least two of these migrations ... Still, I think we would, could and should migrate more questions if migration was possible in a more convenient way than flagging for diamond-mod attention. Our mods have the great habit of not closing a lot of questions by superior vote, but they rather wait until the community does so, which works well. As a result, I often don't think of or bother to request migration, even though it'd make sense.

Comment: Some examples of that are http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48692/4012, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49603/4012 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53435/4012. Do you really think it'd be a bad idea to establish a couple of migration paths? Should we take any other steps to determine sensible options?

Comment: Migration to Maths SE might be useful. I see a lot of questions which are basically, 'what's the right maths notation/spacing/layout...?' rather than 'how do I implement this notation/spacing/layout?'

Comment: @cfr There doesn’t really seem to be [too much migration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RFj8U.png) (away from tex.sx) going on at the moment, but I’d still be up for creating more migration paths. It seems like we’d first need a new meta question where we vote on _answers_ as opposed to comments. Then wait for the powers that be and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

<s>As there seemed to be a fair amount of supporters for SO and ELU (and nobody against new migration paths), but no official SE participation here, I put in a request on meta.so: [Request for new migration paths for tex.sx](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130450/162565)</s>

Oh well, they didn't like it and migrated it back here, where the chance of a SE dev helping with the process of finding appropriate migration paths are much lower. Looks like we need individual answers for the option. Also, could someone with the necessary powers *please provide us with some migration stats*? It'd be pretty bothersome if we had to go through questions by hand.

Comment: SE does monitor child metas.  Migration stats are available at http://tex.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats.  (and have been added to the question)