# Request for new migration paths for tex.sx

Tags: feature-request, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we want more migration paths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/do-we-want-more-migration-paths)

[On tex.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2411/4012), we voted on the question if we wanted more migration paths and if so, which. While nobody thought we didn't need any more migration paths (next to the standard one to meta.tex.sx), here are the vote counts for other sites:

- Stack Overflow: 10
- English L&U: 5
- Graphic Design: 4 (possibly to be added once it's out of beta)
- Super User: 1
- Unix & Linux: 1

Taking into consideration the top two, could an overlord mod please add the migration paths to Stack Overflow and English L&U? (Unless there are any other steps to be taken or thoughts to be considered ...?)

Comment: Since it's site-specific, shouldn't this request go on [meta.tex.se]?

Comment: I don't think comment voting is how the devs determine which sites should be available in the off-topic close dialogue. They usually choose the four which are most often migrated to.

Comment: What trickery is this? You used _comments_? Why not answers? Anyways, migration paths are setup when there's _need_ for them...

Comment: @lunboks: Perhaps, but it's a fact that high-level-requests are dealt with more efficiently on meta.so

Comment: @animuson: To me, it doesn't look like devs regularly go through migration stats of single sites to determine what migration paths might make sense. With SE being as community-driven as it is, I don't see a problem with community input for migration paths. Right now, tex.sx only has one migration path, which is the default one to its own meta site.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: We use comment-voting occasionally on meta.tex.sx. I didn't think down-votes would be necessary -- if someone doesn't like a migration path, they won't have to use it. As for the notion of _need_, I'd assume the voters were taking _need_ into consideration when voting on options, what other reasons would there be?

Comment: While comment votes may work well enough for stuff on your site, you might have better luck with the poll if people provided actual answers, which listed off topic questions that would be appropriate for each target site. Right now, I see ten people who would like to migrate questions that they find off topic to Stack Overflow. I don't think ten comment votes is really a compelling reason to add a new migration path.

Comment: `We use comment-voting occasionally on meta.tex.sx` Well, don't, that's not a good idea. Not only because you can't downvote them, but mainly because comments are ephemeral by nature. And it's not community input if there isn't an option to disagree.