# Migration paths suggestions

Tags: feature-request, migration, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Users with "close" priviledge can mark off-topic questions to be migrated to thie Meta.TeX.SX site. I suggest to add two more migration options:

- [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) - for questions about MathJaX
- [GraphicDesign.SX](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) - for questions purely about typography

I know I can alert the moderators and they can migrate to any site, still I think that these two migration pathes would be helpful.

---

There was a [previous discussion about this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/do-we-want-more-migration-paths) with no real conclusion. The two suggestions I propose here are supported by numerous "likes" in the other thread.

Comment: StackOverflow could also be useful for questions about pre/postprocessing scripts.

Comment: Related, but unsucessful: [Do we want more migration paths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2411)

Comment: Note that Graphic Design is in beta - it might be best if we waited until it goes live before asking for this path.

Comment: @doncherry I remember that there was such a thread, with no conclusion. It seemed to me better to make a fresh one, and I quite happily see that my requests here go along with the most popular suggestions there.

Comment: StackOverflow would also be a nice to have migrate path for the increasing number of r related (and tex unrelated) questions.

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be great to have these migration paths. Another helpful migration target would be [**Super User**](http://www.superuser.com/), for questions that don’t involve *TeX after all. We get these questions occasionally; some of them were simply asked on the wrong site, others are just more likely to get a helpful solution when widening the scope of possible tools beyond *TeX.

Comment: Super User is a bit of a graveyard - even good questions often get little or no attention there.  I think the main purpose of the site was to have a constructive-sounding reason to say certain questions don't belong on SO.  I think I'd rather not have this migration option: I'd rather put these questions out of their misery than create false hope.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the paths already mentioned, I would say:

[Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com),

[Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com)

and

[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Possibly also [vi and vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) but that's still in beta.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Of course, but Joseph Wright said that the number of good questions for migration is too tiny to add migration paths: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/why-cant-we-migrate-off-topic-questions-to-other-stackexchange-sites#comment22060_7413.