# Why can't we migrate off-topic questions to other StackExchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration

[This comment by Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391625/emulating-closures-in-postscript#comment972708_391625) has reminded me a question I wanted to ask.

Every now and then, a good question appears, but which is not concerning LaTeX and friends.

We can only close it as off-topic but not migrate it to another SE site.

Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Non-moderators can only migrate to up to five fixed network sites, these so-called "migration paths" must be set up manually by an SE developer. There has been some discussion about possible sites for this feature, see [Do we want more migration paths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2411/3323) and [Migration paths suggestions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3303/3323), but none are currently set up.

Comment: @diabonas Interesting, thank you! I wonder why nobody has decided yet...

Comment: Because the number of good questions for migration is _tiny_

Comment: @JosephWright There's a reason, then! :)

Comment: @JosephWright But, at least, the migration path from Meta to the main site could be added: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7415/101651. Please :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX the number of "real TeX" questions erroneously posted here on meta is also very small. Only ten all this year, which is low enough that the mods can handle them through flags.

Comment: @Pops Thank you