# Should we migrate "What is this font?" questions to GraphicDesign.SX?

Tags: discussion, scope

In [Stack Exchange podcast #57](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/podcast-57-we-just-saw-this-on-florp/?cb=1) (at the 9'30'' mark), the team agreed that questions of the type

> Could you please identify this font for me?

are on topic on the [Graphic Design site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), which "graduated" only recently.

Since such questions sort are not really on topic on TeX.SX and usually get closed as duplicates of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture), shouldn't we instead migrate them to Graphic Design, from now on?

Comment: Ask to identify a font is different from ask how to identify a font...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I agree with you, there is a nuance there, but the fact is that most "Identify this font" questions get closed as dupes of "*How* can I identify this font?". I think the latter type has its place on TeX.SX, but I don't think the former type does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not necessarily. First, I don't think that especially math font identification is 100% welcome on GD.SE. Second, most often when the question is asked here, it has a subtle sub-question: *"... and how to use this font in LaTeX?"*

This makes the question off-topic on GD.SE and on-topic here. Of course, one can argue that the question should be split then (font identification on GD and font usage here), however, that would be ridiculous.

I therefore think that we should in general let the questioner choose the site himself, and only suggest him migration if we feel it is appropriate.

As for deciding whether migrate these that are duplicates of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture) : I'm certainly against the idea; if it has an answer here, it makes no sense at all to migrate it elsewhere.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. And since Graphic Design is now mature, can we have a [proper migration path, please](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2411/5763)?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that fonts don't work everywhere.  Also, similar fonts can have different names and installs.  So it's better to have a class 'font name' and be done with that.